# Dask array to zarr with unknown shapes

Tags: python, dask, zarr

I am trying to store a dask array in a zarr file.

I have managed to do it when the dask array has a defined shape.

```py
import dask
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory
import zarr


np_array = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=1000)
array = da.from_array(np_array)

with TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
    delayed = da.to_zarr(array, url=tmpdir,
                         compute=False, component='/data')
    dask.compute(delayed)

     z_object = zarr.open_group(tmpdir, mode='r')

     assert np.all(np_array == z_object.data[:])
```

However if I have performed any operation with the dask array, the shape is lost and zarr complains about the Nans in the shape.

```py
# this will fail

np_array = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=1000)
array = da.from_array(np_array)

array = array[array > 5]

with TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
    delayed = da.to_zarr(array, url=tmpdir,
                         compute=False, component='/data')
    dask.compute(delayed)

    z_object = zarr.open_group(tmpdir, mode='r')

    assert np.all(np_array[np_array > 5] == z_object.data[:])
```

This is the raised error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/peio/devel/variation/variation6/variation6/tests/test_zarr.py", line 38, in <module>
    without_shape()
  File "/home/peio/devel/variation/variation6/variation6/tests/test_zarr.py", line 29, in without_shape
    compute=False, component='/data')
  File "/home/peio/devel/variation/pyenv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/array/core.py", line 2808, in to_zarr
    **kwargs
  File "/home/peio/devel/variation/pyenv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zarr/creation.py", line 120, in create
    chunk_store=chunk_store, filters=filters, object_codec=object_codec)
  File "/home/peio/devel/variation/pyenv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zarr/storage.py", line 323, in init_array
    object_codec=object_codec)
  File "/home/peio/devel/variation/pyenv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zarr/storage.py", line 343, in _init_array_metadata
    shape = normalize_shape(shape) + dtype.shape
  File "/home/peio/devel/variation/pyenv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zarr/util.py", line 58, in normalize_shape
    shape = tuple(int(s) for s in shape)
  File "/home/peio/devel/variation/pyenv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zarr/util.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    shape = tuple(int(s) for s in shape)
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Is there a way to store a dask array without known shape into a zarr file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe the usual workflow is to replace values you don't want with NaN instead of removing them from your working array via masking (see `da.where` instead). This way chunk sizes and shape are preserved.

Comment: Or you could fully compute your dask array to a numpy array and then save it.

Comment: Our arrays are like 40M rows per 1K, so we can not compute before saving to zarr.

Answer (score 2):

Zarr expects that chunk shapes are uniform and known beforehand. Dask facilitates this currently by rechunking the array to be uniform. However `array[array > 5]` creates a Dask Array with unknown chunk shapes. So there is no way to rechunk it to be uniform beforehand as the needed information is not present. That said, we could [explain this better](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/5144).

One could workaround this by using Dask operations that return known chunk shapes (as David suggests). Alternatively one could determine the chunk shapes before storing ([at the cost of computing](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/3293)). We could also discuss [extending Zarr to handle this case](https://github.com/zarr-developers/zarr-specs/issues/46), but that is a longer term solution.

Comment: There are two questions that we do not completely understand. 1- Should all the chunks written to disk have to have the same chunk size? 2- Do we have to know beforehand the final total size of the array that we are going to store?

Comment: All chunks should have a known size before writing to disk. They should also be uniform, but Dask handles that for you.